# Issue of ESP32 CAM using esp_http_server, webserver and WiFiClient libraries and Ajax for dual communication

Tags: ajax, http, video-streaming, webserver, esp32

I wish to make use of the arduino standard library of http server to make dual communication between the web page and the esp32 server with camera streaming through WiFi.

It seems I got my result in the screen, I got the camera video as well as some data (LED PWM value as well as antenna received signal strength) from the esp32, but I found continuous and intermittent errors of no response (status 404) in the network traffics of the web page. (Tests were done on both AP mode and Client mode of the esp32, and the results are the same)

My guess is that there may be crash between the libraries of esp_http_server, WebServer and WiFiClient, but it is out my knowledge limit to further investigate this. So I wish to find answer from you. Appreciate for any comment.

Here, I post my code as follow:
(Acknowledgement: I modified the source code from "Random Nerd" to achieve the dual communication.)

```
/*********
  Modified from project at https://RandomNerdTutorials.com
  From Project: ESP32-CAM Remote Controlled Car Robot Web Server
  https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-cam-car-robot-web-server/
  HM, 5 Nov 2023
*********/
// Sample server commands: (assume ip address of the ESP32 is 192.168.8.5)
// 192.168.8.5/control?var=forward&val=1
// 192.168.8.5/control?var=led_PWM&val=10
// If more httpd_query_key_value() is added, use "&" to seperate key/value pair
// 192.168.8.5:81/stream


#include <Arduino.h>
#ifdef ESP32
#include <WiFi.h>
// #include <AsyncTCP.h>
// #include <ESPAsyncWebSrv.h> XXXX
#elif defined(ESP8266)
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESPAsyncTCP.h>
#endif

#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WebServer.h>
WebServer server(80);


#include "esp_camera.h"
#include "esp_timer.h"
#include "img_converters.h"
#include "fb_gfx.h"
#include "soc/soc.h"              // disable brownout problems
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h"     // disable brownout problems
#include "esp_http_server.h"

#include "esp32-hal-ledc.h"       // For Buildin LED



#define Flashlight 4              // Build-in flashlight of ESP32-CAM Board
const int ledFreq = 1000;
const int ledChannel = 4;
const int ledResolution = 12;
int led_intensity = 0;

// Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid = "SSID for Android phone or PC";
const char* password = "123456";



#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER
//#define CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_PSRAM
//#define CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_WITHOUT_PSRAM
//#define CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_PSRAM_B
//#define CAMERA_MODEL_WROVER_KIT

#if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_WROVER_KIT)
  #define PWDN_GPIO_NUM    -1
  #define RESET_GPIO_NUM   -1
  #define XCLK_GPIO_NUM    21
  #define SIOD_GPIO_NUM    26
  #define SIOC_GPIO_NUM    27
  
  #define Y9_GPIO_NUM      35
  #define Y8_GPIO_NUM      34
  #define Y7_GPIO_NUM      39
  #define Y6_GPIO_NUM      36
  #define Y5_GPIO_NUM      19
  #define Y4_GPIO_NUM      18
  #define Y3_GPIO_NUM       5
  #define Y2_GPIO_NUM       4
  #define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM   25
  #define HREF_GPIO_NUM    23
  #define PCLK_GPIO_NUM    22

#elif defined(CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_PSRAM)
  #define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     -1
  #define RESET_GPIO_NUM    15
  #define XCLK_GPIO_NUM     27
  #define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     25
  #define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     23
  
  #define Y9_GPIO_NUM       19
  #define Y8_GPIO_NUM       36
  #define Y7_GPIO_NUM       18
  #define Y6_GPIO_NUM       39
  #define Y5_GPIO_NUM        5
  #define Y4_GPIO_NUM       34
  #define Y3_GPIO_NUM       35
  #define Y2_GPIO_NUM       32
  #define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    22
  #define HREF_GPIO_NUM     26
  #define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     21

#elif defined(CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_WITHOUT_PSRAM)
  #define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     -1
  #define RESET_GPIO_NUM    15
  #define XCLK_GPIO_NUM     27
  #define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     25
  #define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     23
  
  #define Y9_GPIO_NUM       19
  #define Y8_GPIO_NUM       36
  #define Y7_GPIO_NUM       18
  #define Y6_GPIO_NUM       39
  #define Y5_GPIO_NUM        5
  #define Y4_GPIO_NUM       34
  #define Y3_GPIO_NUM       35
  #define Y2_GPIO_NUM       17
  #define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    22
  #define HREF_GPIO_NUM     26
  #define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     21

#elif defined(CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER)
  #define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
  #define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
  #define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
  #define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
  #define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27
  
  #define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
  #define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
  #define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
  #define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
  #define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
  #define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
  #define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
  #define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
  #define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
  #define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
  #define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22

#elif defined(CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_PSRAM_B)
  #define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     -1
  #define RESET_GPIO_NUM    15
  #define XCLK_GPIO_NUM     27
  #define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     22
  #define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     23
  
  #define Y9_GPIO_NUM       19
  #define Y8_GPIO_NUM       36
  #define Y7_GPIO_NUM       18
  #define Y6_GPIO_NUM       39
  #define Y5_GPIO_NUM        5
  #define Y4_GPIO_NUM       34
  #define Y3_GPIO_NUM       35
  #define Y2_GPIO_NUM       32
  #define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
  #define HREF_GPIO_NUM     26
  #define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     21

#else
  #error "Camera model not selected"
#endif

#define MOTOR_1_PIN_1    14
#define MOTOR_1_PIN_2    15
#define MOTOR_2_PIN_1    13
#define MOTOR_2_PIN_2    12

#define PART_BOUNDARY "123456789000000000000987654321"
static const char* _STREAM_CONTENT_TYPE = "multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=" PART_BOUNDARY;
static const char* _STREAM_BOUNDARY = "\r\n--" PART_BOUNDARY "\r\n";
static const char* _STREAM_PART = "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Length: %u\r\n\r\n";

httpd_handle_t camera_httpd = NULL;
httpd_handle_t stream_httpd = NULL;



static const char PROGMEM INDEX_HTML[] = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ESP32-CAM Robot</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      body { font-family: Arial; text-align: center; margin:0px auto; padding-top: 30px;}
      table { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
      td { padding: 8 px; }
      .button {
        background-color: #2f4468;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin: 6px 3px;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
      }
      img {  width: auto ;
        max-width: 100% ;
        height: auto ; 
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>ESP32-CAM Robot</h1>
    <img src="" id="photo" >
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="center">
          <button class="button" id="button_forward" ontouchstart="button_state_forward = true;" >forward</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center">
          <button class="button" onmousedown="toggleCheckbox('left');" ontouchstart="toggleCheckbox('left');" onmouseup="toggleCheckbox('stop');" ontouchend="toggleCheckbox('stop');">Left</button>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <button class="button" onmousedown="toggleCheckbox('stop');" ontouchstart="toggleCheckbox('stop');">Stop</button></td><td align="center"><button class="button" onmousedown="toggleCheckbox('right');" ontouchstart="toggleCheckbox('right');" onmouseup="toggleCheckbox('stop');" ontouchend="toggleCheckbox('stop');">Right</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="center">
          <button class="button" onmousedown="toggleCheckbox('backward');" ontouchstart="toggleCheckbox('backward');" onmouseup="toggleCheckbox('stop');" ontouchend="toggleCheckbox('stop');">Backward</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div align="center">
    <input type="range" class="slider" id="LEDslider" min="0" max="255" value="0"
      onchange="try{
      fetch(document.location.origin+'/control?var=led_PWM&val='+this.value);
      }catch(e){}">
    </div>
    <div class="LED_feedback_value">
      <h4>The feedback of LED intensity: <span id="LED_feedback_value">0</span></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="RSSI">
      <h4>The Received Signal Strength (RSSI): <span id="RSSI_feedback_value">N/A </span>dBm</h4><br>
    </div>

    <script>
    var counter1 = 0;
    let panelButtons = 0;
    var button_state_forward = false;

    function toggleCheckbox(x) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("GET", "/control?var=" + x + "&val=0", true);              // URL = server_ip_address/control?var=xxx&val=xxx
      xhr.send();
    }
    
    setInterval(function(){
      controlPanel();
      counter1+=1;
      if (counter1==2){
        getLEDval();              //It was found that the 1st XML Request will be lost
        getLEDval();              //So a 2nd XML Request will be repeated.
      }
      if (counter1==4){
        counter1=0;
        getRSSI();
        getRSSI();
      }
    },200); 


    function controlPanel(){
      fetch(document.location.origin+'/control?var=led_PWM&val='+ document.getElementById("LEDslider").value);
      if(button_state_forward){
        toggleCheckbox('forward');
        button_state_forward=false;                           // URL = server_ip_address/control?var=xxx&val=xxx
      }
    }

    function getLEDval(){
      var xhttpr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttpr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
          document.getElementById("LED_feedback_value").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      }
      xhttpr.open("GET", "readLED", true);
      xhttpr.send();
    }

    function getRSSI(){
      var xhttpr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttpr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
          document.getElementById("RSSI_feedback_value").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      }
      xhttpr.open("GET", "readRSSI", true);
      xhttpr.send();
    }

    window.onload = document.getElementById("photo").src = window.location.href.slice(0, -1) + ":81/stream";
    // setInterval(controlPanel,1000);                  // Javascript does not support multiple setInterval()

    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
)rawliteral";


static esp_err_t index_handler(httpd_req_t *req){
  httpd_resp_set_type(req, "text/html");
  return httpd_resp_send(req, (const char *)INDEX_HTML, strlen(INDEX_HTML));
}

static esp_err_t stream_handler(httpd_req_t *req){
  camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
  esp_err_t res = ESP_OK;
  size_t _jpg_buf_len = 0;
  uint8_t * _jpg_buf = NULL;
  char * part_buf[64];

  res = httpd_resp_set_type(req, _STREAM_CONTENT_TYPE);
  if(res != ESP_OK){
    return res;
  }

  while(true){
    fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
    if (!fb) {
      Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
      res = ESP_FAIL;
    } else {
      if(fb->width > 400){
        if(fb->format != PIXFORMAT_JPEG){
          bool jpeg_converted = frame2jpg(fb, 80, &_jpg_buf, &_jpg_buf_len);
          esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
          fb = NULL;
          if(!jpeg_converted){
            Serial.println("JPEG compression failed");
            res = ESP_FAIL;
          }
        } else {
          _jpg_buf_len = fb->len;
          _jpg_buf = fb->buf;
        }
      }
    }
    if(res == ESP_OK){
      size_t hlen = snprintf((char *)part_buf, 64, _STREAM_PART, _jpg_buf_len);
      res = httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, (const char *)part_buf, hlen);
    }
    if(res == ESP_OK){
      res = httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, (const char *)_jpg_buf, _jpg_buf_len);
    }
    if(res == ESP_OK){
      res = httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, _STREAM_BOUNDARY, strlen(_STREAM_BOUNDARY));
    }
    if(fb){
      esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
      fb = NULL;
      _jpg_buf = NULL;
    } else if(_jpg_buf){
      free(_jpg_buf);
      _jpg_buf = NULL;
    }
    if(res != ESP_OK){
      break;
    }
    //Serial.printf("MJPG: %uB\n",(uint32_t)(_jpg_buf_len));
  }
  return res;
}

static esp_err_t cmd_handler(httpd_req_t *req){
  char*  buf;
  size_t buf_len;
  char variable[32] = {0,};
  char value[32] = {0,};                                        // Assume max. of 32 characters??

  // Serial.println("Received a command!");

  buf_len = httpd_req_get_url_query_len(req) + 1;
  if (buf_len > 1) {
    buf = (char*)malloc(buf_len);
    if(!buf){
      httpd_resp_send_500(req);
      return ESP_FAIL;
    }
    if (httpd_req_get_url_query_str(req, buf, buf_len) == ESP_OK) {
      if (httpd_query_key_value(buf, "var", variable, sizeof(variable)) == ESP_OK && 
          httpd_query_key_value(buf, "val", value, sizeof(value)) == ESP_OK) {
      } else {
        free(buf);
        httpd_resp_send_404(req);
        return ESP_FAIL;
      }
    } else {
      free(buf);
      httpd_resp_send_404(req);
      return ESP_FAIL;
    }
    free(buf);
  } else {
    httpd_resp_send_404(req);
    return ESP_FAIL;
  }

  sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
  int res = 0;
  
  /* Control Decode */
  if(!strcmp(variable, "forward")) {
    Serial.println("Forward");
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_1_PIN_1, 1);
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_1_PIN_2, 0);
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_2_PIN_1, 1);
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_2_PIN_2, 0);
  }
  else if(!strcmp(variable, "left")) {
    Serial.println("Left");
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_1_PIN_1, 0);
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_1_PIN_2, 1);
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_2_PIN_1, 1);
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_2_PIN_2, 0);
  }
  else if(!strcmp(variable, "right")) {
    Serial.println("Right");
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_1_PIN_1, 1);
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_1_PIN_2, 0);
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_2_PIN_1, 0);
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_2_PIN_2, 1);
  }
  else if(!strcmp(variable, "backward")) {
    Serial.println("Backward");
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_1_PIN_1, 0);
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_1_PIN_2, 1);
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_2_PIN_1, 0);
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_2_PIN_2, 1);
  }
  else if(!strcmp(variable, "stop")) {
    Serial.println("Stop");
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_1_PIN_1, 0);
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_1_PIN_2, 0);
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_2_PIN_1, 0);
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_2_PIN_2, 0);
  }
  else if(!strcmp(variable, "led_PWM")){
    led_intensity = atoi(value)/4;                                // val =
    Serial.printf("Command: LED PWM = %u\n",led_intensity);       // val
    ledcWrite(Flashlight, led_intensity);                         // val 
  }
  else {
    res = -1;
  }

  if(res){
    return httpd_resp_send_500(req);
  }

  httpd_resp_set_hdr(req, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  return httpd_resp_send(req, NULL, 0);
}

void startCameraServer(){
  httpd_config_t config = HTTPD_DEFAULT_CONFIG();
  config.server_port = 80;
  httpd_uri_t index_uri = {
    .uri       = "/",
    .method    = HTTP_GET,
    .handler   = index_handler,
    .user_ctx  = NULL
  };

  httpd_uri_t cmd_uri = {
    .uri       = "/control",
    .method    = HTTP_GET,
    .handler   = cmd_handler,
    .user_ctx  = NULL
  };
  httpd_uri_t stream_uri = {
    .uri       = "/stream",
    .method    = HTTP_GET,
    .handler   = stream_handler,
    .user_ctx  = NULL
  };
  if (httpd_start(&camera_httpd, &config) == ESP_OK) {
    httpd_register_uri_handler(camera_httpd, &index_uri);
    httpd_register_uri_handler(camera_httpd, &cmd_uri);
  }
  config.server_port += 1;
  config.ctrl_port += 1;
  if (httpd_start(&stream_httpd, &config) == ESP_OK) {
    httpd_register_uri_handler(stream_httpd, &stream_uri);
  }
}

void handleRSSI() {
  server.send(200, "text/plane", String(WiFi.RSSI())); //Send LED  value only to client ajax request  
  Serial.println("RSSI request received and XMLHttpResponse sent!");
// Serial.printf("RSSi: %ld dBm\n",WiFi.RSSI())
}

void handleLED() {
  server.send(200, "text/plane", String(led_intensity)); //Send LED  value only to client ajax request  
  Serial.println("LED PWM request received and XMLHttpResponse sent!");
}

void setup() {
  WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_CNTL_BROWN_OUT_REG, 0);                //disable brownout detector
  
  ledcSetup(ledChannel, ledFreq, ledResolution);            // Setup LED PWM freq & resolution
  ledcAttachPin(Flashlight, 4);

  pinMode(MOTOR_1_PIN_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MOTOR_1_PIN_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MOTOR_2_PIN_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MOTOR_2_PIN_2, OUTPUT);
  
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setDebugOutput(false);
  
  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG; 
  
  if(psramFound()){
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_VGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 10;
    config.fb_count = 2;
  } else {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 12;
    config.fb_count = 1;
  }
  
  // Camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }
  // Wi-Fi connection
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  
  Serial.print("Camera Stream Ready! Go to: http://");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  
  // Start streaming web server
  startCameraServer();

  server.on("/readRSSI", handleRSSI);
  server.on("/readLED", handleLED);                                 //To get update of ADC Value only

  server.begin();                                                   //Start server
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");


  ledcWrite(Flashlight, 0x01);
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
  delay(1);
}
```

The web page with Network traffic & errors:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJe3i.jpg)

Tried the code in both AP & Client Modes and its works, but with intermittant error 404, also due to properties of Ajax, it seem I should keep the socket as 80 for Webserver, and it may be another reason of crash ....

**

## -- Further Edited with other test

**

For simplicity, as usual, I ran all the code, and observed many network errors occured, next, for simplicity, I keeped the Web page being run and I reprogramed the ESP32 without the  startCameraServer() function of the official http server, then I found no error at all for the xhr requests/ returns for every interval of 200ms.

So it seem esp_http_server and WebServer libraries have some collision there ....

[experimental result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl7qb.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some efforts, it make simplier to me to use one http server libary for all the video streaming, handling http requests and response ajax requests.
Finally ESPAsycnWebSvr library was adopted. A sample code from GitHub of this library was modified (https://gist.github.com/me-no-dev)

Now, the ESP32-CAM (AI Thinker) provides 2 ways communication with Camera streaming.
Both AP mode and Client mode was tested.

Test Result:
[Network Performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx9ys.jpg)

The code is shared for those who need this functions:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include "ESPAsyncWebSrv.h"

#include "soc/soc.h"              // disable brownout problems
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h"     // disable brownout problems


#define Flashlight 4              // Build-in flashlight of ESP32-CAM Board
const int ledFreq = 1000;
const int ledChannel = 4;
const int ledResolution = 12;     // 12 bits give good resolution at low lux
int led_intensity = 0;


// For AI Thinker ESP32-CAM Board ONLY
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27

#define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22



// WiFi credentials
const char* ssid = "SSID";
const char* password = "Password";


typedef struct {
        camera_fb_t * fb;
        size_t index;
} camera_frame_t;

#define PART_BOUNDARY "123456789000000000000987654321"
static const char* STREAM_CONTENT_TYPE = "multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=" PART_BOUNDARY;
static const char* STREAM_BOUNDARY = "\r\n--" PART_BOUNDARY "\r\n";
static const char* STREAM_PART = "Content-Type: %s\r\nContent-Length: %u\r\n\r\n";

static const char * JPG_CONTENT_TYPE = "image/jpeg";
static const char * BMP_CONTENT_TYPE = "image/x-windows-bmp";

AsyncWebServer server(80);


const char* htmlHomePage PROGMEM = R"HTMLHOMEPAGE(
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <style>
      .slider {
        width: 20%;
        height: 10px;
        border-radius: 3px;
      }
    </style>
  
  </head>
  <body class="noselect" align="center" style="background-color:white">
    <h1><br></h1>
    <img id="cameraImage" src="" style="width:400px;height:250px">
    <h2><br></h2>
    
    <div class="slidecontainer">LED_Brightness
        <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="0" class="slider" id="LEDslider" oninput='sendButtonInput("LED",value)'>
    </div>
    <div class="LED_feedback_value">
      <h4>The feedback of LED intensity: <span id="LED_feedback_value">0</span></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="RSSI">
      <h4>The Received Signal Strength (RSSI): <span id="RSSI_feedback_value">N/A </span>dBm</h4><br>
    </div>


    <script>
      var counter1 = 0;
      let panelButtons = 0;

      function controlPanel(){
        fetch(document.location.origin+'/control?var=led_PWM&val='+ document.getElementById("LEDslider").value);
      }

      function getLEDval(){
        var xhttpr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttpr.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("LED_feedback_value").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          }
        }
        xhttpr.open("GET", "readLED", true);
        xhttpr.send();
      }

      function getRSSI(){
        var xhttpr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttpr.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("RSSI_feedback_value").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          }
        }
        xhttpr.open("GET", "readRSSI", true);
        xhttpr.send();
      }


      setInterval(function(){                     // pressure test,  every 200ms
        controlPanel();
        counter1+=1;
        if (counter1==2){
          getLEDval();
        }
        if (counter1==4){
          counter1=0;
          getRSSI();
        }
      },200); 


      window.onload = document.getElementById("cameraImage").src = window.location + "stream";
    </script>
  </body>    
</html>
)HTMLHOMEPAGE";


class AsyncBufferResponse: public AsyncAbstractResponse {
    private:
        uint8_t * _buf;
        size_t _len;
        size_t _index;
    public:
        AsyncBufferResponse(uint8_t * buf, size_t len, const char * contentType){
            _buf = buf;
            _len = len;
            _callback = nullptr;
            _code = 200;
            _contentLength = _len;
            _contentType = contentType;
            _index = 0;
        }
        ~AsyncBufferResponse(){
            if(_buf != nullptr){
                free(_buf);
            }
        }
        bool _sourceValid() const { return _buf != nullptr; }
        virtual size_t _fillBuffer(uint8_t *buf, size_t maxLen) override{
            size_t ret = _content(buf, maxLen, _index);
            if(ret != RESPONSE_TRY_AGAIN){
                _index += ret;
            }
            return ret;
        }
        size_t _content(uint8_t *buffer, size_t maxLen, size_t index){
            memcpy(buffer, _buf+index, maxLen);
            if((index+maxLen) == _len){
                free(_buf);
                _buf = nullptr;
            }
            return maxLen;
        }
};

class AsyncFrameResponse: public AsyncAbstractResponse {
    private:
        camera_fb_t * fb;
        size_t _index;
    public:
        AsyncFrameResponse(camera_fb_t * frame, const char * contentType){
            _callback = nullptr;
            _code = 200;
            _contentLength = frame->len;
            _contentType = contentType;
            _index = 0;
            fb = frame;
        }
        ~AsyncFrameResponse(){
            if(fb != nullptr){
                esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
            }
        }
        bool _sourceValid() const { return fb != nullptr; }
        virtual size_t _fillBuffer(uint8_t *buf, size_t maxLen) override{
            size_t ret = _content(buf, maxLen, _index);
            if(ret != RESPONSE_TRY_AGAIN){
                _index += ret;
            }
            return ret;
        }
        size_t _content(uint8_t *buffer, size_t maxLen, size_t index){
            memcpy(buffer, fb->buf+index, maxLen);
            if((index+maxLen) == fb->len){
                esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
                fb = nullptr;
            }
            return maxLen;
        }
};

class AsyncJpegStreamResponse: public AsyncAbstractResponse {
    private:
        camera_frame_t _frame;
        size_t _index;
        size_t _jpg_buf_len;
        uint8_t * _jpg_buf;
        uint64_t lastAsyncRequest;
    public:
        AsyncJpegStreamResponse(){
            _callback = nullptr;
            _code = 200;
            _contentLength = 0;
            _contentType = STREAM_CONTENT_TYPE;
            _sendContentLength = false;
            _chunked = true;
            _index = 0;
            _jpg_buf_len = 0;
            _jpg_buf = NULL;
            lastAsyncRequest = 0;
            memset(&_frame, 0, sizeof(camera_frame_t));
        }
        ~AsyncJpegStreamResponse(){
            if(_frame.fb){
                if(_frame.fb->format != PIXFORMAT_JPEG){
                    free(_jpg_buf);
                }
                esp_camera_fb_return(_frame.fb);
            }
        }
        bool _sourceValid() const {
            return true;
        }
        virtual size_t _fillBuffer(uint8_t *buf, size_t maxLen) override {
            size_t ret = _content(buf, maxLen, _index);
            if(ret != RESPONSE_TRY_AGAIN){
                _index += ret;
            }
            return ret;
        }
        size_t _content(uint8_t *buffer, size_t maxLen, size_t index){
            if(!_frame.fb || _frame.index == _jpg_buf_len){
                if(index && _frame.fb){
                    uint64_t end = (uint64_t)micros();
                    int fp = (end - lastAsyncRequest) / 1000;
                    // log_printf("Size: %uKB, Time: %.0fms (%.1ffps)\n", _jpg_buf_len/1024, fp, 1000./fp);           // METER !
                    lastAsyncRequest = end;
                    if(_frame.fb->format != PIXFORMAT_JPEG){
                        free(_jpg_buf);
                    }
                    esp_camera_fb_return(_frame.fb);
                    _frame.fb = NULL;
                    _jpg_buf_len = 0;
                    _jpg_buf = NULL;
                }
                if(maxLen < (strlen(STREAM_BOUNDARY) + strlen(STREAM_PART) + strlen(JPG_CONTENT_TYPE) + 8)){
                    //log_w("Not enough space for headers");
                    return RESPONSE_TRY_AGAIN;
                }
                //get frame
                _frame.index = 0;

                _frame.fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
                if (_frame.fb == NULL) {
                    log_e("Camera frame failed");
                    return 0;
                }

                if(_frame.fb->format != PIXFORMAT_JPEG){
                    unsigned long st = millis();
                    bool jpeg_converted = frame2jpg(_frame.fb, 80, &_jpg_buf, &_jpg_buf_len);
                    if(!jpeg_converted){
                        log_e("JPEG compression failed");
                        esp_camera_fb_return(_frame.fb);
                        _frame.fb = NULL;
                        _jpg_buf_len = 0;
                        _jpg_buf = NULL;
                        return 0;
                    }
                    // log_i("JPEG: %lums, %uB", millis() - st, _jpg_buf_len);                                        // METER !!
                } else {
                    _jpg_buf_len = _frame.fb->len;
                    _jpg_buf = _frame.fb->buf;
                }

                //send boundary
                size_t blen = 0;
                if(index){
                    blen = strlen(STREAM_BOUNDARY);
                    memcpy(buffer, STREAM_BOUNDARY, blen);
                    buffer += blen;
                }
                //send header
                size_t hlen = sprintf((char *)buffer, STREAM_PART, JPG_CONTENT_TYPE, _jpg_buf_len);
                buffer += hlen;
                //send frame
                hlen = maxLen - hlen - blen;
                if(hlen > _jpg_buf_len){
                    maxLen -= hlen - _jpg_buf_len;
                    hlen = _jpg_buf_len;
                }
                memcpy(buffer, _jpg_buf, hlen);
                _frame.index += hlen;
                return maxLen;
            }

            size_t available = _jpg_buf_len - _frame.index;
            if(maxLen > available){
                maxLen = available;
            }
            memcpy(buffer, _jpg_buf+_frame.index, maxLen);
            _frame.index += maxLen;

            return maxLen;
        }
};


void handleRoot(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) 
{
  request->send_P(200, "text/html", htmlHomePage);
}

void handleNotFound(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) 
{
    request->send(404, "text/plain", "ESP32: File Not Found");
}



void streamJpg(AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    AsyncJpegStreamResponse *response = new AsyncJpegStreamResponse();
    if(!response){
        request->send(501);
        return;
    }
    response->addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    request->send(response);
}



void handleControl(AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    if(!request->hasArg("var") || !request->hasArg("val")){
        request->send(404);
        return;
    }
    String var = request->arg("var");
    const char * variable = var.c_str();
    int val = atoi(request->arg("val").c_str());

    sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
    if(s == NULL){
        request->send(501);
        return;
    }


    if(!strcmp(variable, "led_PWM")){
      led_intensity = val/4;
      // Serial.printf("Command: LED PWM = %u\n",led_intensity);                  // This line would slow down the ESP32
      ledcWrite(Flashlight, led_intensity);                                       // val 
    }  
    else {
        log_e("unknown command %s", var.c_str());
        request->send(404);
        return;
    }
    // log_d("Got setting %s with value %d. Res: %d", var.c_str(), val, res);

    AsyncWebServerResponse * response = request->beginResponse(200);
    response->addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    request->send(response);
}

void setup(){

  WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_CNTL_BROWN_OUT_REG, 0);                // Disable brownout detector

  ledcSetup(ledChannel, ledFreq, ledResolution);            // Setup LED PWM freq & resolution
  ledcAttachPin(Flashlight, 4);                             // Channel 4
  ledcWrite(Flashlight, 0x03);                              // Startup indicated by low light

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setDebugOutput(true);



  // Start Wifi and init camera //

  // Start Wifi


 IPAddress local_ip(192,168,4,1);
 IPAddress gateway(192,168,4,1);
 IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);
 WiFi.softAPConfig(local_ip, gateway, subnet);             //AP Mode
 WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);                              //
 Serial.print("AP IP address: ");                          //
 Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());                          //


  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);                               // Client Mode
  WiFi.setSleep(false);                                     //
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {                   //
    delay(500);                                             //
    Serial.print(".");                                      //
  }                                                         //
  Serial.println("");                                       //
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");                         //
  Serial.print("Camera Stream Ready! Go to: http://");      //
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());                           //



  // init camera
  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG; 
  if(psramFound()){
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_VGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 10;
    config.fb_count = 2;
  } else {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 12;
    config.fb_count = 1;
  }


  // camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    log_e("ERROR : Camera init failed with error 0x%x\n", err);
    return;
  }
  else {
    log_d("Camera init OK");
  }

  sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
  log_d("Sensor PID : %d\n",s->id.PID);
    
  // =============================================




  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, handleRoot);
  server.on("/stream", HTTP_GET, streamJpg);
  server.on("/control", HTTP_GET, handleControl);
  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);


// Ajax xhr response to Web page
  server.on("/readLED", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *req){
    req->send(200, "text/plain",String(led_intensity));
  });

  server.on("/readRSSI", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *req){
    req->send(200, "text/plain",String(WiFi.RSSI()));
  });


  server.begin();
}

// ==== UPDATE : main loop ====
void loop(){
vTaskDelay(5000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
}
// ============================
```

Comment: *I EDITED the CODE*  ---  For stable AP Mode, I explicitly define the ip, gateway address with subnet with the following code, you need to comment the portion of Client Mode if you want to use AP Mode and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the duplicate ajax calls definitely don't look right

```
setInterval(function(){
  controlPanel();
  counter1+=1;
  if (counter1==2){
    getLEDval();              //It was found that the 1st XML Request will be lost
    getLEDval();              //So a 2nd XML Request will be repeated.
  }
  if (counter1==4){
    counter1=0;
    getRSSI();
    getRSSI();
  }
},200);
```

Basically, you are calling getLEDval() or getRSSI() twice straight away, Ajax is by nature asynchronous so you are not giving a chance for the first call to complete and you are already sending the second request.

Plus, those calls are happening on an interval which makes everything even more Async and all these Ajax calls can get jammed in a big queue because you are repeating the cycle 5 times a second (your browser can probably handle it fine but and ESP will struggle with more than 5-6 simultaneous requests.

** **EDIT** **

Ok, I've modified your Javascript a bit, it's quick and dirty and needs implementing error checks otherwise it could hang on a failed Ajax call

All Ajax calls will be going through a single utility function that takes as arguments the query, the next function you want to execute and how long to wait before calling it and a callback that will be executed in the function that called this Ajax with the response value.

It should ensure that things happen in order and apart from the toggleCheckbox() you should have only one Ajax floating and waiting to complete at a time.

The code below starts from the "LEDslider" where I've replaced the on change to a reusable function call

```
<input type="range" class="slider" id="LEDslider" min="0" max="255" value="0"
  onchange="controlPanel()">
</div>
<div class="LED_feedback_value">
  <h4>The feedback of LED intensity: <span id="LED_feedback_value">0</span></h4>
</div>
<div class="RSSI">
  <h4>The Received Signal Strength (RSSI): <span id="RSSI_feedback_value">N/A </span>dBm</h4><br>
</div>

<script>

var button_state_forward = false;

function toggleCheckbox(x) {
  ajax("/control?var=" + x + "&val=0")

}

function controlPanel(){
  ajax("/control?var=led_PWM&val=" + document.getElementById("LEDslider").value,getLEDval,400,function(){
    if(button_state_forward){
      toggleCheckbox('forward');
      button_state_forward=false; 
    }
    
  })
}

function getLEDval(){
  ajax("readLED",getRSSI, 400, function(response){
      document.getElementById("LED_feedback_value").innerHTML = this.responseText;

  })
}

function getRSSI(){
  ajax("readRSSI",controlPanel, 200, function(response){
    document.getElementById("RSSI_feedback_value").innerHTML = response;

  })
}

function ajax(query,nextCallFunction, nextCallDelay, responseCallback){
  
    let xhttpr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttpr.onreadystatechange = function(){

      if (this.readyState == 4){
        if(this.status == 200){
            if(responseCallback){
                responseCallback(this.responseText);
            }
        }
        if(nextCallFunction){
            setTimeout(function(){
                nextCallFunction()
            },nextCallDelay)
        }
      }
    }
    xhttpr.open("GET", query, true);
    xhttpr.send();
}

window.onload = document.getElementById("photo").src = window.location.href.slice(0, -1) + ":81/stream";

controlPanel(); //kick start everything

</script>
```

As I said, this is quick and dirty and hasn't been tested but an approach like this should at least prevent your browser from overheating.

You said you've tried ESPAsyncServ, that's fine but it is a bit of a beast and I don't think your issue is with handling servers requests in an Async way but rather the browser side to work Async.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, Gizmo, the duplication is my intentional test and I think it's not the main reason.

Comment: I have tried to do it right by giving only ONE XML http request for every TWO seconds, the result is still the same, I.e. error, success alternatively. So, my coming consideration is to change the webserver to ESPAsynServer and test again .....

Comment: Another observation is that if I left the ESP32 continue to run, I found the video will have delay after 10 minutes run and my PC's fan start to speed up .... :

Comment: It's frustrated, the libraries crashed when I changed the "Webserver.h" to "ESPAsyncServ.h ......

Comment: I've edited my answer, hope it helps

Comment: Hi Gizmo, thanks for you help. Tried and, still no luck. It seem not related to delay, I will further analysis the code.

Comment: Hi, my latest test seem proved the libraries crashed together, I first keep all the things run, getting many Network error message. For simplicity, I keep the Web page but reprogram the ESP32-CAM with the function  startCameraServer( ) disabled, then after the connection, I find all the xhr returned with no error!!  (time between xhr request is 200ms)

Comment: Don't have an ESP32 cam at hand but I've found some ancient library that I've tried and I think it worked, it may be different from the one you are using. I've lost my full test code but I've found some snippets, no other documentation though! Here's a download link: https://chipchop.io/downloads/_temps/ESP32_Cam.zip

Comment: Hi Gizmo, thanks for you share. I obtained some code samples from author of the ESPAyncWebSrv library. I completely throw away the official http server and use this Asyn Server to generate Jpeg stream, priminarily succeeded. I will try to completely use this server to replace all the previous functions. Cheer! and thanks for you kind advices.